# How to use Distribute Points Nodes correctly on uneven terrain. (Hexagon World)

Tags: modeling, modifiers, node-editor, geometry-nodes, project

I'm watching some tutorials about geometry nodes to create my hexagonal world. And I finished my world, but I don't know how to put more details, like vegetation/trees and stuff. When i use the node *Distribute Point on face* in my uneven terrain, the trees, to example, are created in underground, i have trees under trees, i have trees on the skies. And my objective is create the trees just in my hexagon terrain, and not in the water too.

this is my world

[image]

And this my world when i try put some trees.

[image]

[image]

This is the best result I got at the moment with the Tarou help, but I still have tree in the water and everywhere and some trees still change your scale in Z axis maybe.

I'm a little bit lost.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your title to something more relevant to your issue ... like a question you are looking for. So others that will look for similar issue can find your. Thank you

Comment: i agree with vklidu but i still don't know what do you want? your trees are in your world...you can plug in multiple noodles in your join geometry node...so just add another branch with vegetation...

Comment: Thank you for alert me. English is not my primary language, so sometimes I use translater to help me with difficult words, and sometimes I forget that the translator changes the sentences to "better understanding". Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

if I get this right you are actually quite close. You can drag and drop a collection into the geometry nodes editor.

[image]

As you see I use a collection info node that points to the collection containing all the different objects to distribute.
If you don't want to Distribute them all in one place make sure to check **separate children**.  Make sure to check **Pick Instance** in the Instance on Points node.

I really hope this is the answer you are looking for! Keep it up.

Bonus:

This Setup for example adds more control notice the Integer node on the second Instance on Points node to the right. By changing this number we can select a specific object from the collection to selected. Change the number 'til you get the desired result.
[image]

The geometry proximity node with the delete geometry node both set to points, shall prevent that the new created stuff spawns too close to already existing stuff from the other distribute points on faces, by changing the less than value, you can change basically the value how close the points of the other distribute points are allowed to "spawn". This however doesn't prevent clipping 100% of the time since a single distribute points on faces could emit their own points to close to each other depending on the seed, then you can use the same approach to delete it's own points that are close together.

Comment: Hey Tarou, thanks for help. This is so useful, and I learned so much with this. But my really problem is I don't  know how put my trees just in my terrain hexagon. I didn't express myself right the first time. Every time when i put my trees in my world, i have trees in everywere. On the ground, trees  inside trees, trees in the water, tree with diferent scales. I have a diferent levels of altitude in my world and the higher the more deformed the scale of my trees.